# How to set table position beside image with css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set my table's position right of my image.

Here's my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style type="text/css">
  .podium { display: block; margin-left: 300; margin-top: 500; position: static; }
  table { position: relative; left: 100px; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="podium.jpg" class="podium">
 <table border="5px">
  <tr>
   <td>aaa</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried this, but it didn't work.

How can I make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap image and table in a div and than You can use flex and flex-order property of [Flex order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items#The_order_property).

```css
#wrapper{ display: flex; }
#image{ order:2; width: 100px; height:100px; margin-left:15px}
#table{ order:1; }
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSNyNcwf4fDjX_2L4mUcJNmg92fOmWlDTYxcefggBG0VAr6MX32" class="podium" id='image'>
<table border="5px" id='table'>
  <tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```